# Spring Integration MQTT shared subscriptions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, mqtt, spring-integration-mqtt

I need to support mqtt in my project. I use RabbitMQ as a broker. I developed Spring Boot application and i use Spring Integration MQTT.

```
@Configuration
public class MqttConfig {
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MqttPahoClientFactory clientFactory() {
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setServerURIs(new String[]{ "tcp://localhost:1883" });
        options.setUserName("user_admin");
        options.setPassword("password".toCharArray());
        factory.setConnectionOptions(options);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageProducer inbound() {
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("siSampleConsumer", clientFactory(), "example_topic");

        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setQos(1);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                System.out.println("MESSAGE: " + message.getPayload());
            }

        };
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-mqtt</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I run two instance of same application in different port 8081 and 8082

```
  java -jar target/mqtt_project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=8081
  java -jar target/mqtt_project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=8082
```

I use MQTTX Client Toolbox for testing.
When i send several message on the topic `example_topic`
it always arrives at the same port 8082

```
MESSAGE: Hello World // port 8082

MESSAGE: Hello World // port 8082

MESSAGE: Hello World // port 8082
```

How can i implement MQTT shared subscriptions to allow client load balancing, which means that the broker splits the message load equally amongst the subscribed clients for a particular topic ?

```
MESSAGE: Hello World // port 8081

MESSAGE: Hello World // port 8082

MESSAGE: Hello World // port 8081

MESSAGE: Hello World // port 8082
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that rabbitmq supports shares subscriptions? ([this blog post](https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2023/07/mqtt5/#shared-subscriptions) and [this issue](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/8936) suggest that support will be added in a future release).

Comment: Is it possible to implement some custom solution ?

Comment: I'm sure there are options. but this depends upon your precise requirements (for instance you could accept messages via MQTT. route them into a queue and consume with AMQP).

Answer (score 0):

If the broker supports shared subscriptions then using them is just a case of adding the right prefix to the topic the clients subscribe to.

E.g.

```
$shared/group-identifier/example_topic
```

Where `group-identifier` is a unique id for the collection of clients

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem with same type of code. I solved it by starting the instances with `$share/groupID/my/topic` where groupID is group ID of the subscriber applications in which multiple application instances should be start.

**NOTE**: ***groupID value should be the same for all the instances***.

I ran 4 application instances and when I published the messages on `my/topic` 4 times, application instances recieved messages in round-robin manner.

In my case I was using the eclipse mosquitto mqtt broker. I referred  https://cedalo.com/blog/mqtt-shared-subscriptions-guide/ as a guide. This guide will also show how mqtt broker sends messages among multiple groups where each group has multiple instances.

This approached will work like a charm if you want your MQTT traffic to load balance among multiple subscriber applications in round-robin manner.

Thanks.

Comment: Let me know the corrections here if any.

Comment: What mqtt version do you use because it looks like shared subscriptions supports only version mqtt5

Comment: @Romillion I've used mqtt5 on the broker side and at handler side I've used same code as you mentioned.

Comment: Just added multiple instances on the same group ID as mentioned